# error with scope of variables

Tags: c++, scope, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently writing a program in C++ which takes information from a .txt file and allocates it dynamically to be referred to later.  The information is in a format (firstname lastname) (salary) (deductions) (%bonus).  I've created a struct in a header file that is as follows:

```
    struct PayrollInfo
    {
        string first, last;
        float salary, deduction, bonus;
        PayrollInfo *next;
    };
```

My problem is that when I call on variables in a function that is called by the main function, the compiler gives me an error saying the variables are "out of scope".  I was under the impression that because I declared the struct pointers in the main function that those would carry over to functions called on.  What can I do to fix this?  I've included my code below.  Open is a function that I have that opens the file and returns 0 if it exists, etc.  Also, I'm new to using dynamic memory allocation so if there are any visible errors with my Read() function, please let me know!

```
    main()
    {
         PayrollInfo *head, *tail, *newp, *tmp;
         head = tail = newp = tmp = NULL;

         while(newp = Read() )
         .
         .
         .

    PayrollInfo *Read()
    {
         PayrollInfo *tmp = NULL;
         if (Open() == 0)
         {
              tmp = new PayrollInfo;
              tmp->first = first;
              tmp->last = last;
              tmp->salary = salary;
              tmp->bonus = bonus;
              tmp->deduction = deduction;
         }
         else
              return NULL;
         return tmp;
    }
```

Comment: whoa you need an `int` before that `main()`!

Comment: Tip: Never use `new`. In this case, a smart pointer would do the same, but better. Of course better than that even is not using dynamic allocation if you can help it. Without pointers, the code shown would still work.

Comment: Make sure you initialize the next pointer when you new up PayrollInfo. Otherwise you'll have garbage there, which is never fun to debug.

Comment: What variable is it warning you about? salary? Or something else?

Comment: i thought the int is assumed isnt it? im actually supposed to use dynamic allocation so cant get around that.. its warning me about all the variables. how do i initialize the pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately since I'm a new user I can't comment or I would... but there is one thing I notice with your code that's a little odd which I can't really tell too much more about without seeing the rest of your main function, and that's that you're trying to use the variables first, last, salary, bonus and deduction as if they're global variables when they appear to not be defined as such anywhere else in your program.

If your Open() function is meant to define those variables, it'll need to do so outside of its scope if you want to use them outside of its scope - declaring them beforehand and then modifying your Open() function to accept references to them as parameters, then modifying them that way, could produce the results you're looking for. As it is, though, you haven't declared any of those variables anywhere that I can see, and if they're declared inside Open() then you have a problem.

Post the code of your Open() function as well as everything prior to your main() function (includes, variable definitions, etc) and maybe the problem will be more apparent.